# Stuck for 3 days on Wolframs Intro - Help!

Tags: list-manipulation, style

I've been going through Wolfram's elementary introduction and solved every problem but have been stuck on this one for 3 days. I must be thinking wrong. I'd appreciate a hint.

Use Part to make a list of the first 50 digits of 2^1000, in which each digit has a size equal to 3 times its value.

I got this far on  affecting the list, but can't figure how to get Style into it to change font size.

```
Table[n 3, {n, IntegerDigits[2^1000][[1 ;; 50]]}]
```

Comment: `Table[If[n == 0, "", Style[n , 3 n]], {n, IntegerDigits[2^1000][[1 ;; 50]]}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon I don't think that the `If` statement is necessary. `Table[Style[n, 3 n], {n, IntegerDigits[2^1000][[1 ;; 50]]}]` yields the same output.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 - With v13.0.1 on a Mac, without the `If` the `0` does not have zero height, i.e., it is not invisible. The height of `0` appears about the same as that of `2`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks for letting me know about that. Have not tried that on my Mac with v13 yet. v12 on linux worked without the `If` statement, that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: Thanks, all. I had a feeling I could do it with If, but since the wasn't yet in the book it would mean I hadn't really learned how Style works. I see the problem, now. But frankly, when I'm up to If I'm going to use it instead of struggling ;)